# iPhone/iOS SDK: Autorotate main view, but not child view?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, ios, autorotate

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have a single view ("primaryView"), controlled by a customized view controller.  primaryView contains a scrollview, which contains an image.  Sitting on top of the scroll view (NOT inside it) is a small view ("buttonsView") containing a few buttons.

Basically, when the user rotates the phone, I want buttonsView to autorotate to match the new orientation, but I want the scrollview to remain exactly as it is, and NOT rotate.

Is there a way to do this?  Right now, primaryView is autorotating, and taking both subviews (the scrollview and buttonsView) with it, which is no good.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system will not autorotate unless all visible views consent to autorotation. What you can do, then, is to detect orientation changes, and set an appropriate affine transform for the non-rotating views, essentially to undo the system's rotation.

You can use [`willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to fade out the controls, then [`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to fade them back in at the correct location.

Comment: I want to make sure that the view whose rotation I'm undoing isn't going to look like it's rotating and then rotating back... how would I make sure the animation doesn't happen for that view?